# Android: Widget: 'Embedded/Predefined' Images Missing?

Tags: android, image, widget

In design mode, my icons show up. The first is the launcher icon (a vector image) and the last is just a standard material vector asset.

They show up fine in the design view "preview" in my configuration activity. But won't on the home screen; I'm assuming this is some sort of path or permissions problem that the service can't resolve. Do I need something that leads to @drawable? If so what?

Design Mode:

[image]

On phone:

[image]

Manifest:

```
<receiver android:name=".widget.ProgressWidgetProvider">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE"/>
    </intent-filter>

    <meta-data
        android:name="android.appwidget.provider"
        android:resource="@xml/app_widget_provider_info" />
</receiver>
```

app_widget_provider_info.xml

```
<appwidget-provider xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:minWidth="240dp"
    android:layout_height="20dp"
    android:updatePeriodMillis="86400000"
    android:initialLayout="@layout/widget_progress"
    android:resizeMode="horizontal"
    android:widgetCategory="home_screen"       
    android:configure="com.gumonshoe.granger.widget.ProgressWidgetSettings" />
```

XML for Widget:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="70dp"
    android:background="@color/grangerGray"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/wdgIconClickable"
        android:layout_width="30dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@color/grangerGray"
        android:clickable="true"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_launcher_foreground" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/weight"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="10"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/wdgProgTarget"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="8"
            android:paddingBottom="4dp"
            android:text="TextView"
            android:textAlignment="center" />

        <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/wdgProgressBar"
            style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingLeft="8dp"
            android:progressDrawable="@drawable/granger_progress_light" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/wdgWordCount"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingTop="4dp"
            android:text="5000/6546"
            android:textAlignment="center" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/wdgBtnLogToTarget"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:backgroundTint="@color/grangerBlue"
        android:paddingVertical="20dp"
        android:tint="@color/grangerYellow"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_time_log_black_24dp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

#### Requested Data from Comments

compileSdkVersion 28, minSdkVersion 28, targetSdkVersion 28; 
vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary is not present in the gradle, but again vectors show up in the application itself, just not in a widget on the homescreen.

#### workaround

Doing this in the java during update, fixes the problem, but I shouldn't have to run code to set the resource correctly.

```
views.setInt(R.id.wdgBtnLogToTarget, "setImageResource", R.drawable.ic_stat_name);
views.setInt(R.id.wdgIconClickable, "setImageResource", R.drawable.ic_launcher_foreground);
```

Comment: What version of Android is your phone running? I think support for vector drawables varies depending on the version. Also, do you have `vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true` in your build.gradle file?

Comment: @JamesAllen its the pixel 3 xl, so Android 9